# Moving index.html as part of node build

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm, vue.js

I am building my first Vue.js project.  The main `index.html` used to sit in the root of the project.  If I ran `npm run dev`, it would use this one as the default page in the browser.

I have just integrated Firebase by installing `firebase cli` and running `firebase init`. This placed a new `index.html` template inside the `dist` directory.  Now when I deploy using `firebase deploy`, it uses the new `/dist/index.html`, not the old one in the project root.  This means I now have two `index.html` files, each being used for different situations.

It seems I have a couple of options:

1. scrap `~/index.html` and just use firebase's version in `dist`

   - this will mean my `npm run dev` will not work
2. keep both copies manually in sync

   - not a good idea
3. scrap `~/dist/index.html` and get my build workflow to:

   1. do all the stuff it currently does
   2. copy `~/index.html` to `~/dist/index.html`
   3. run `firebase deploy`

The last option seems best - **how do I do it?**

FYI - here's the scripts section of `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "watchify": "watchify -vd -p browserify-hmr -e src/main.js -o dist/build.js",
    "serve": "http-server -o -c 1 -a localhost",
    "dev": "npm-run-all --parallel watchify serve",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production browserify -g envify -p [ vueify/plugins/extract-css -o dist/build.css ] -e src/main.js | uglifyjs -c warnings=false -m > dist/build.js"
  }
```

Comment: Option 4. Switch to vue-cli webpack, in which the `index.html` in `dist` is created from the dev `index.html`, so you only have to update one html file.

Comment: @EricGuan, yes, this is pretty much what I want to do.  How do I do it?

Comment: If you install the vue-cli webpack, it is the default behavior. https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack. Anything you edit in `index.html` will be copied over to `dist/index.html`. The plugin that performs this is `HtmlWebpackPlugin`